# Is $\frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}$ uniformly continuous at $(0,\infty)?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

*Please don't close my question, no it has not been answered yet, the other question uses differentiability, which i cant use and dont ask about. (Moreover, i dont want to copy my homework from someone elses work, i ask if i did fine also)

Is $f(x) = \frac{\ln (x+1)}{x}$ uniformly continuous at $(0,\infty)?$

---

My attempt: *I cant use differentiability

$(1)$ 
We can say that $f(x)$ is built from division of 2 continuous functions at the interval $[0, \infty)$ therefore, $f(x)$ is continuous at $[0, \infty)$.

Using L'Hopital we find that:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0
$$

Therfore we can say:

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists M_1 > 0, \forall x > M_1: |f(x) - 0| = |f(x)| < \varepsilon/4.   
$$

Therefore, we can say: 
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists M_2 > 0, \forall x,y > M_2, |x-y| < \delta: |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2 < \varepsilon
$$

Namely, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous at $[M_2,0)$

At $[0,M_2], f(x)$ is uniformly continuous by Cantor theorem for continuous functions at closed intervals.

Conclusion, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous at $[0,\infty)$ and particularly at $(0, \infty)$.

Is it correct? And is there a better way?

Comment: To clarify, is this the same as your question [3500488](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500488/is-frac-ln-x1x-uniformly-continious-at-0-infty) but you want your proof to be verified?

Comment: That approach works. It is missing to cover the case of $x,y$ close together $|x-y|<\delta$ but $x\in [0,M_2]$ and $y\in (M_2,+\infty)$.

Comment: "We can say that $f(x)$ is built from division of 2 continuous functions at the interval $[0,\infty)$ therefore, $f(x)$ is continuous at $[0,\infty)$": **no**.

Comment: @Jam its my question, but its written to me that it is closed.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy why should i cover that case? i showed 2 intervals that the function is uniformly continious, why should i take elements from both intervals at the same time?

Comment: I think in the future you should try to make it clearer that you want a proof verification (with the proof-verification tag and putting it in the title), so people don't close your question.

Comment: @Gae S. can you explain why no?

Comment: @Alon Because uniform continuity means that $\forall \epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$  you have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. As you see, there is no restriction of $x,y$ being both $>M_2$ or $\leq M_2$. So, yes, the case of them being on different sides of $M_2$ should be covered. Missing this case is a very common mistake. That is why it is the very first thing that I looked at when I read your question.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy
Can you tell me how do i cover this case?

And, i thought that saying that when we have two intevals ay which the function has uniform continuity, we can conclude that at the uniform of the intervals, the function will also be uniform continious, so i dont understand the logic of covering the case from my point of view and as a consequence - from what you expleained.

Comment: @Alon The explanation that you gave for $f$ being continuous is fine on $(0,+\infty)$, since quotient of continuous function is continuous, as long as the denominator is non-zero. That $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, can be argued just by computing $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1=f(0)$, if they defined $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy its a very important argument to say that its on closed interval including $0$, therfore, and as they didnt define $f(0) = 1$, how can we conclude that the function is continious at $0$?

Comment: @Alon The case $x\leq M_2$ and $y>M_2$ can be covered in many ways. You could use Cantor on a larger $[0,M_3]$, for some $M_3>M_2$. Or you can use the continuity of $f$ at $M_2$ the same way that you used the limit at $\infty$. It is as simple as what you have already done. It is just that it is a case that it is often forgotten.

Comment: If they didn't define $f$ at $0$, then you can define it at $x=0$. Define it as $f(0)=1$ such that the new function is continuous on $[0,M_2]$ and you can apply Cantor to it. Then your argument will have to end saying that since the extended function is uniformly continuous, then the original function is also uniformly continuous.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I understand what you say but i cant convince my self. Again if i say that there are two intervals, which when we look at each seperatly, we conclude $f$ is uniform continuity at both, seperatly, then the union is automaticly has the property of uniformly continious for $f$, why not? i see what you said using the definition, but i look seperatly at both intervals. *And the intervals has a overlap point

Comment: If you can't explain how you pass from the property on the two intervals to the property on their union, that means that the argument is not complete. Just saying that the property holds in the union is no a proof.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Ok so i should say, that  $\forall x \in [0,M_2], \forall y \in [M_2, M_3], M_3 > M_2$ we can define the interval $[0,M_3] \subset [0,\infty)$, but $f$ is uniformly continious at $[0, \infty)$ therfore $f$ is uniformly continious at $[0,M_3]$?

Comment: The only thing which puzzles me is that you cannot use differentiability but you apply L'H. How can you apply L'H without using differentiability.

Comment: I cant use LHopital as well, but i didnt want to ask too many questions and ask as well about the the limit, which i dont realy know how to calculate without LHopital, i would like to ask about that as well but it seems too much and my main question is about uniform continuity

Comment: Regarding @Gae.S. 's comment:  $1$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.  $x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.  $1/x$ is not.

Comment: @EricTowers can i define a value, as i was suggested and by that solve the problem? because i want to use the closed left interval $[0, \infty)$ or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No.  You are told to work with a given function, which *is* continuous on $[0,\infty)$.  You should re-read @Gae.S. 's comment to remind yourself which of your proof's claims is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine. If you look carefully, your approach can be used to prove the following more general statement:

**Claim** Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. If the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**Note** If you are not allowed to use differentiability, then you should not use L'H.

You can prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=0$ "elementary" the following way:

**Step 1:** Show by induction that for each $n \geq 4$ you have $2^n \geq n^2$.

**Step 2** For each $x \in [4, \infty)$ pick $n$ so that $2^n \leq x+1 <2^{n+1}$.

Then 
$$\log(x+1)< (n+1) \log(2) \\
x>2^n-1>2^{n-1} \geq (n-1)^2 \\
0< \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}<\frac{(n+1) \log(2) }{(n-1)^2}
$$

Now, it is easy to make $\frac{(n+1) \log(2) }{(n-1)^2}< \epsilon$ by making $n>N$ and hence $x>A$ for some $N,A$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt realy understand the last line. what is $A$?

Comment: @Alon To prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ you need to show that, for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $A$ so that, if $x>A$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. You probably use a different letter for $A$.

Comment: I made a mistake, $|\frac{(n+1) \log(2) }{(n-1)^2}| < |\frac{n \log(2)+\log(2) }{n(n-2)}| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ ,here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=\frac{\log (t+1)}{t}$. We  prove that $f$ is a contraction.

We compute $$f'(t)=\frac{1}{t(t+1)}-\frac{\log(t+1)}{t^2}.$$ 
Then $f'$ is continous on $(0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{t\to \infty} f'(t)= 0 $, and you can check that $\lim_{t\to 0^+} f'(t)<\infty$. This implies that $|f'|$ is bounded, i.e. $|f'(t)|<M$ for some $M>0$.

By the mean value theorem $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$$
for all $x,y>0$.

In particular $f$ is uniformally continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said, i cant use differentiability, but next chapter that i will learn i will, but this exercise doesnt include that. thanks again

Comment: @Alon Oops sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: I will come back to this when i will learn this, and maybe i would like to ask questions, so thanks, plz dont delete the answer